# How to make material-tab-strip scrollable in Angular Dart?

Tags: dart, responsive-design, tabs, material-design, angular-dart

Is it possible to make material-tab-strip scrollable when the tab strip overflows or when the tabs overlap each other?

```
<material-tab-strip 
                    (beforeTabChange)="onBeforeTabChange($event)"
                    [tabLabels]="categories"
                    [activeTabIndex]="currentTabIndex">
</material-tab-strip>
```

Comment: Hi, yous work with angularDart so can you give me an advice please ? I'd like to learn a new frontend framework but I'm confused between AngularDart and Angular (typescript). In fact I'd like to work with dart language that's why I tend to AngularDart but I find it not very used all over the world and no enough tutorials exist. What do you suggest , can you give me an advice please ?

Comment: Hello @hous . I'm sorry I didn't see your comment earlier. I would recommend vuejs over the others. AngularJS is another option.

Comment: yes I have already start with VueJs. Yesterday I bought a course VueJs on Udemy ;) thanks

Comment: Also AngularDart and VueDart are other options. It depends on which technology you prefer and which is best for you to meet your requirements.